# How can I create 1000000 x 1000000 sparse matrix using Java Colt?

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix, colt

```
public class SparseMatrix
{       
     static SparseObjectMatrix2D matrix = new SparseObjectMatrix2D(1000000, 1000000);

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
            matrix.set(1, 2, 3.0);
     }      
}
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: matrix too large at
cern.colt.matrix.impl.AbstractMatrix2D.setUp(Unknown Source) at
cern.colt.matrix.impl.AbstractMatrix2D.setUp(Unknown Source) at
cern.colt.matrix.impl.SparseObjectMatrix2D.<init>(Unknown Source) at
cern.colt.matrix.impl.SparseObjectMatrix2D.<init>(Unknown Source) at
SparseMatrix.<clinit>(SparseMatrix.java:18) Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: Please post the error message you're getting.

Comment: Please actually [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: matrix too large
 at cern.colt.matrix.impl.AbstractMatrix2D.setUp(Unknown Source)
 at cern.colt.matrix.impl.AbstractMatrix2D.setUp(Unknown Source)
 at cern.colt.matrix.impl.SparseObjectMatrix2D.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at cern.colt.matrix.impl.SparseObjectMatrix2D.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at SparseMatrix.<clinit>(SparseMatrix.java:18)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

Comment: 8E12 bytes if it were full - are you getting an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: also don't post code in a reply comment, update your post with the details.

Comment: `matrix too large` - It's probably too large. After all, you're  creating a 1 *trillion* cell matrix.

Comment: Maybe it's too large because it says it's too large.

Comment: Can I create a matrix more than 10000 X 10000?

Comment: Computer says no. Do you really need such a matrix? Maybe create several smaller matrices and then combine them.

Comment: If I am not mistaken that would be around `47 GB` of RAM if that were *just* `10000x10000` 32 bit values (with no overhead of any object or container etc)

Comment: Well yeah, that is why I am trying to use sparse matrix and I am ending up with errors. I gotta store adjacency matrix for a million nodes.

Comment: Then store 100 matrices for 10000 nodes each. Or consider using a database with so much data.

Comment: I just read your recent questions to figure out what you're trying to do. Please use HashMap<> for adjacency lists as suggested below. The matrix approach will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. From the [documentation](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/SparseObjectMatrix2D.html#SparseObjectMatrix2D(int,%20int)):

> **Throws:**
>   `IllegalArgumentException` - if `rows<0 || columns<0 || > (double)columns*rows > Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Instead of creating a matrix addressed with x and y coordinates, returning a `Value`, create a `HashMap<Coordinates, Value>`, where `Coordinates` is a simple class holding x and y.